# Stuck in python combinations using itertools

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm using the itertools module in python. I found that combinations_with_replacement does not give me all the combinations.

```
>>>import itertools
>>>[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('AB', 3)]
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]
```

It does not give me ['A','B','A'] nor ['B','A','B'].

Does anyone know why is this and, more importantly, how to correct it?

Comment: Yes. I was using a combination of this list and it's reversed one.

Comment: The reason is simple: the definition of `combinations_with_replacement` is not what you expect. Read the doc ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `product` with 3 repeats:

```
import itertools
print [list(x) for x in itertools.product('AB', repeat=3)]
```

Gives:

> [['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]

Remember that using list comprehension you can always resort to:

```
ab_str = "AB"
# don't have to use +, can do (x, y, z,)
print [x + y + z for x in ab_str for y in ab_str for z in ab_str]
```

Gives:

> ['AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB']